# Issues with Oracle database using ROWNUM

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, pagination

Trying to make pagination for news test task in a traineeship. Can't make it work getting following error in the 7th line:

*ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB*

Sql script is below. At first I get news sorted by comments count and modification date. Then I choose only those which row numbers are between 1 and 2:

```
SELECT NEWS_ID, TITLE, SHORT_TEXT,
    FULL_TEXT, CREATION_DATE, MODIFICATION_DATE
FROM
    ((SELECT APPROPRIATE_NEWS.*, ROWNUM R FROM
        (SELECT *
        FROM ((SELECT NEWS_ID, TITLE, SHORT_TEXT,
                    FULL_TEXT, CREATION_DATE, MODIFICATION_DATE, COMMENTS_COUNT
               FROM NEWS JOIN (SELECT NEWS_ID, COUNT(*) COMMENTS_COUNT
                               FROM COMMENTS
                               GROUP BY NEWS_ID) NEWS_STAT USING(NEWS_ID))
        UNION
        (SELECT NEWS_ID, TITLE, SHORT_TEXT,
                    FULL_TEXT, CREATION_DATE, MODIFICATION_DATE, 0 COMMENTS_COUNT
        FROM NEWS
        WHERE NEWS_ID NOT IN(SELECT NEWS_ID
                             FROM COMMENTS))) ALL_NEWS_STAT
        WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NEWS_AUTHOR NA
                     WHERE NA.NEWS_ID = ALL_NEWS_STAT.NEWS_ID AND AUTHOR_ID = 1)
            AND NEWS_ID IN (SELECT NEWS_ID
                          FROM NEWS_TAG
                          WHERE TAG_ID IN (1, 2)
                          GROUP BY NEWS_ID
                          HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
        ORDER BY COMMENTS_COUNT DESC, MODIFICATION_DATE) APPROPRIATE_NEWS) NEWS_PAGE)
WHERE R BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

Databse Script

```
CREATE TABLE NEWS
(
    NEWS_ID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    SHORT_TEXT NVARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
    FULL_TEXT NCLOB NOT NULL,
    CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    MODIFICATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TAGS
(
    TAG_ID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    TAG_NAME NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE NEWS_TAG
(
    NEWS_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    TAG_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(NEWS_ID) REFERENCES NEWS(NEWS_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(TAG_ID) REFERENCES TAGS(TAG_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE AUTHORS
(
    AUTHOR_ID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    AUTHOR_NAME NVARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    EXPIRED TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE NEWS_AUTHOR
(
    NEWS_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    AUTHOR_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(NEWS_ID) REFERENCES NEWS(NEWS_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(AUTHOR_ID) REFERENCES AUTHORS(AUTHOR_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE COMMENTS
(
    COMMENT_ID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    NEWS_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    COMMENT_TEXT NCLOB NOT NULL,
    CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(NEWS_ID) REFERENCES NEWS(NEWS_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I know the database is quite terrible but I'm forced to work with it. Everything works fine in mysql replacing rownum stuff with limit keyword

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where (at which line and position) do you get that message? It's weird, nothing in your tables is NCLOB... wondering where that is coming from. With that said: in your NEWS table definition you have short_text at 200 characters and full_text at only 100 characters, what's up with that?

Comment: @mathguy Sorry, it was a test database. I get error at the 7th line. Position: FULL_TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, the set operation UNION does not support CLOB/NCLOB datatypes. UNION ALL does. UNION ALL seems like the right operation in your case anyway - there should be no overlap between the two operands (resulting row sets) on the two sides of UNION. Change UNION to UNION ALL and it will work.  Good luck!

**Added**: You may wonder how I came up with that answer. I am not an experienced player, I had no clue. For future reference, here's how I went about finding the answer.

Big, big plus: you provided the CREATE TABLE statements for the tables, and your full query. This allowed me to recreate the whole set-up, down to the exact error message, on my machine.

First I re-created the table NEWS with FULL_TEXT as CLOB instead of NCLOB; I got the same error. Good news; it wasn't specific to NCLOB, which meant there is more of a chance to figure it out. (There is much more information about CLOB than about NCLOB.) Then I changed again, this time to VARCHAR2, and the query compiled correctly. So there was something about CLOB that caused the problem.

Then I said, let me narrow it down to a simpler query. I discarded UNION and the second branch of UNION. Now the query compiled perfectly fine. Then I did the same but only KEEPING the second branch and commenting out the first branch. Again, success.

OK, at this point it was pretty clear that UNION itself was the problem, not anything else. Google "Oracle union and CLOB" and there it was, plenty of info about it.

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot!!! You saved me after hours and hours of searching and f words (sorry for my english if it's strange)!

Comment: Glad it helped - this is what SO is for!